# How do I navigate back to list page after delete from detail page?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

Here is my delete code that is on my detail page:

```
/// <reference path="~/GeneratedArtifacts/viewModel.js" />

myapp.ViewReceipt.DeleteReceipt_execute = function (screen) {

    msls.showMessageBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", {
        title: "Confirm Delete",
        buttons: msls.MessageBoxButtons.okCancel
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result === msls.MessageBoxResult.ok) {
            screen.getReceipt().then(function (receipt) {
                receipt.deleteEntity();
                //Save changes
                myapp.applyChanges().then(null, function fail(e) {
                    // If error occurs, show the error.
                    msls.showMessageBox(e.message, { title: e.title }).then(function () {
                        // Discard Changes
                        screen.details.dataWorkspace.ApplicationData
                            .details.discardChanges();
                    });
                });
                //navigate back to list page
                this.window.location.href = '#/BrowseReceipts.lsml'; //this doesn't work for me
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by revising your code to use the myapp.navigateBack() method.

This method should be executed, once the applyChanges has successfully completed, by implementing its onComplete callback, as shown in the following revised example:

```js
msls.showMessageBox("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", {
    title: "Confirm Delete",
    buttons: msls.MessageBoxButtons.okCancel
}).then(function (result) {
    if (result === msls.MessageBoxResult.ok) {
        screen.getReceipt().then(function (receipt) {
            receipt.deleteEntity();
            // Save changes
            myapp.applyChanges().then(function onComplete() {
                myapp.navigateBack();
            }, function fail(e) {
                // If error occurs, show the error.
                msls.showMessageBox(e.message, { title: e.title }).then(function () {
                    // Discard Changes
                    screen.details.dataWorkspace.ApplicationData.details.discardChanges();
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```